# Check if a post has any term in this custom taxonomy?

Tags: custom-taxonomy, taxonomy

This,

```
if( has_term( 'jazz', 'genre' ) ) {
    // do something
}
```

will check if a post has the term `jazz` from the custom taxonomy `genre`. But how to check if a post belongs to a custom taxonomy `genre`? No matter whatever term it has, as long as it has something from the `genre` taxonomy, it will check.

So something like this,

```
if ( has_taxonomy('genre') ) {
    // whether it's jazz, blues, rock and roll; doesn't matter as long as the post has any of them.
}
```

Comment: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_post_terms

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can have the term input empty, e.g.

```
if( has_term( '', 'genre' ) ) {
    // do something
}
```

to see if the current post object has any terms in the genre taxonomy.

It uses [`is_object_in_term()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_object_in_term/) where:

> The given terms are checked against the object’s terms’ term_ids,
>   names and slugs. Terms given as integers will only be checked against
>   the object’s terms’ term_ids. If no terms are given, determines if
>   object is associated with any terms in the given taxonomy.

Answer (score 5):

```
if ( has_term('', 'genre') ) {
    // whether it's jazz, blues, rock and roll; doesn't matter as long as the post has any of them.
}
```

would return true if the post contains any term in the *genre* taxonomy

Comment: I don't think the function `has_taxonomy()` exists in the WordPress core.

Comment: Sorry, that was a mistake. Changed `has_taxonomy` to `has_term`